# "program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault" in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am having issues in collecting and validating a user's integer input for a grade in my program. the grade is stored in a structure along with its accompanying course name in courseRecord. there should be 2 of these structures created and stored as an array of size 2 within the studentRecord structure, where the data should be stored.

I know this is not my only problem, as I can see by the watches on the debug menu that whilst there is a substructure of a kind in studentRecord, there are not 2 as I intended. for the moment I am only working with the 1 available, and then I intend to adapt the code to include a second.

the specific error of "program recieved signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault", which points to when the user first enters any numerical grade leads me to believe that there is a memory allocation error somewhere. I have attempted to use the malloc function, but the fact that it is still not working means I have obviously not used it correctly. I am using the current GNU GCC compiler/linker as is available in the code:blocks software. Here is the code:

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "defs.h"

int main()
{
getGradeAverage();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

defs.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 40

typedef struct courseRecord
{
char courseName [MAX_LENGTH+1];
int grade;
}courseRecord[2];

typedef struct studentRecord
{
char studentName [MAX_LENGTH+1];
struct courseRecord;
}studentRecord;


void getUserName ();
void getCourse (index);
void GPAPrint ();
void getGradeAverage ();
```

lib.c

```
#include "defs.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

//Gets username, assigns it to struct studentRecord.
//Known working.

void getUserName ()
{
studentRecord sr;
printf ("please enter the your name:");
scanf("%40[^\n]%*c",sr.studentName);
}
//Gets course name and grade, assigns to array of size 2 of struct courseRecord in studentRecord
void getCourse ()
{
int i;
studentRecord sr;
printf("please enter the name of course 1:");
scanf("%40[^\n]%*c",sr.courseName);
malloc(sizeof(sr.grade));
do{
    printf("please enter the grade for course 1:");
    scanf("%i",sr.grade);
    if ((scanf("%i",sr.grade))!=1)
    {
        printf("sorry, that grade is in letter form. Please try again.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        continue;
    }
    else if (sr.grade!=-2||0||2||4||6||8||10||12);
    {
        printf("sorry, that grade is not on the scale. Please try again.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        continue;
    }
} while(true);
}

void GPAPrint ()
{
int GPA;
studentRecord sr;
/*
GPA=(sr.grade[1]+sr.grade[2])/2
printf("Student name: %s\n",&sr.studentName\n\n);
printf("Course: %s\nGrade:%i\n"sr.coursename[1], sr.grade[1])
printf("Course: %s\nGrade:%i\n"sr.coursename[2], sr.grade[2])
printf("total GPA is %i",GPA)
*/


}

void getGradeAverage ()
{
getUserName();
getCourse();
GPAPrint();
}
```

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: what did the debugger tell you?

Comment: `scanf("%i",sr.grade);` --> `scanf("%i", &sr.grade);` Also you have many mistakes.

Comment: the debugger output was: Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Child process PID: 5412
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Comment: 2nd edit: BLUEPIXY was right, the ampazand was needed in this case. now to fix the rest of it myself :D